# how to show latest xkcd in dashboard on startup?

Tags: start-up, dashboard

Dashboard can display images on startup. I was wondering how would I give it latest xkcd comic from xkcd-mode?

Comment: What's "dashboard" ?

Comment: if [this](https://github.com/rakanalh/emacs-dashboard) what you mean, it's better to ask that feature (or hints to implement) from the maintainer.

Comment: @phils dashboard is a startup screen that allows you to customize what you want to see on start up (recent projectile projects, files, agenda, etc.) [source](https://github.com/rakanalh/emacs-dashboard)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`xkcd-mode` uses `~/.emacs.d/xkcd/` to cache the images, `xkcd-cache-dir`.

So, you just need to set dashboard image variable, `dashboard-banner-official-png`, as the last cached image, `xkcd-latest`, and consider that dashboard only accepts png images.

```
(require 'xkcd)

;; to update cached xkcd
(with-temp-buffer
  (xkcd)
  (xkcd-kill-buffer))

;; setting dashboard image (png)
(let ((last-xkcd-png (concat xkcd-cache-dir (number-to-string xkcd-latest) ".png")))
  (if (file-exists-p last-xkcd-png)
      (setq dashboard-banner-official-png last-xkcd-png)))
```

If you want to get random xkcd comic, you can use:

```
(require 'xkcd)

;; to get a rand comic and to set dashboard image (png)
(let ((rand-id-xkcd nil))
  (with-temp-buffer
    (setq rand-id-xkcd (string-to-number (xkcd-rand)))
    (xkcd-kill-buffer))
  (let ((last-xkcd-png (concat xkcd-cache-dir (number-to-string rand-id-xkcd) ".png")))
    (if (file-exists-p last-xkcd-png)
    (setq dashboard-banner-official-png last-xkcd-png))))
```

If you also want to change dashboard text below the image, `dashboard-banner-logo-title`, just change `(xkcd)` for `(setq dashboard-banner-logo-title (xkcd))` or `(setq rand-id-xkcd (string-to-number (xkcd-rand)))` for `(setq rand-id-xkcd (string-to-number (setq dashboard-banner-logo-title (xkcd-rand))))`.

Don't forget to put this after dashboard config in your init file.

Comment: I had to change `(setq dashboard-banner-official-png last-xkcd-png)`to  `(setq  dashboard-startup-banner last-xkcd-png)` to get it working.